# render function doesn't work in Twig, using Silex TwigServiceProvider

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

Function `render` in Twig template `{{ render(url('header')) }}` is causing the error:

> "The function "render" does not exist in "layout.twig""

I'm using `Silex` with `TwigServiceProvider`.
The Silex documentation states:

> A render function is also registered to help you render another controller from a template.

What is the problem?

Comment: IIRC `render` is a symfony-specific function

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at composer [Twig Bridge](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html#symfony-components-integration)

Install it using :

```
 composer require symfony/twig-bridge
```

Then follow the guide !

Comment: It's installed.

**composer.json:**
`{
     "require:": {
        "silex/silex": "1.3",
        "twig/twig": "^1.22",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.2",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^2.7"
     }
}`

Comment: It was installed at the beginning. 
Maybe it reqiure some tricky initialisation?
I have only this:
`$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array( 
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../../views',
));
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());`

Comment: That's all for me ! It should be okay now.

Answer (score 1):

I add this: `$app->register(new Silex\Provider\HttpFragmentServiceProvider());` 
and `render` function starts working.